# How to make Kibana dashboard to autocomplete my document fields

Tags: kibana

I have an index with many field names. Im using Kibana 3 to visualise the analytics from the said index. Since I have a lot of fields,im finding it difficult to set the field names,each time I do some analytics in Kibana. Does Kibana provide an autocomplete,feature which enable me for inputting my fields easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you have asked is already there in Kibana-3 in the name "preload fields". It can be set up,by clicking the settings icon to the right and selecting the "index" option (on the top left side,2nd from left) . There you can find a check box named "preload fields". Just check it and you will have your fields,preloaded where ever you want to use it. The following screen shot explains it for you:
[image]
There are a few more convenient features that would allow users to use Kibana-3 with ease,you can find them [here](http://blog.qbox.io/tutorial-simple-analysis-using-kibana)

Comment: I couldn't find this for Kibana 5. Do you happen to know where that could be?